# android-market tag should be renamed or synonymed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Google has renamed the Android market to "**Google Play**", hence I think the [android-market](/questions/tagged/android-market) tag should also be renamed, to [google-play](/questions/tagged/google-play). (or at least, have any questions tagged [google-play](/questions/tagged/google-play) synonym to [android-market](/questions/tagged/android-market).)

I see a synonym was suggested. But it needs voted. When it gets to +4 it would be automatically approved. **[Please cast your vote on the suggested synonym.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-market/synonyms)**

Comment: I don't know the android market much, but is there a difference between "Android Market" and "Google Play" that would make answer about "Android Market" not relevant for "Google Play" ?

Comment: As of today, "Android Market" is known as "Google Play", even google searches redirect you there, as well as the application's name on Android phones. So I think it's safe to say that the answer to your question is no.

Comment: I agree with this, but we **should not** re-tag the existing questions, as they may have information specific to the market instead of google play.

Comment: Technically, it's "Google Play Store".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the synonym [google-play](/questions/tagged/google-play) ← [android-market](/questions/tagged/android-market).

I did not merge the tags given [Richard's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125140/android-market-tag-should-be-renamed-or-synonymed#comment505318_125140). If anyone has further reason why the tags should be *merged*, feel free to comment or answer here.