# Merge [android-market] and [google-play]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Android Market was the old name of Google's app store, which is now called Google Play. Due to this, we have [android-market](/questions/tagged/android-market) and [google-play](/questions/tagged/google-play). Currently, the Google Play tag is suggested as a synonym for the Android Market tag (admittedly, this was my fault. It should be the other way around).

Could [android-market](/questions/tagged/android-market) be merged with the tag [google-play](/questions/tagged/google-play)?

Having Google Play as the tag would be better as it is the current name of the App Store, and hence has a better context in the questions asked these days. Also, people use the old android-market tag even now (most recent question being yesterday). Merging them both into google-play will reduce confusion and improve searchability of questions on that topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: So, something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125140/android-market-tag-should-be-renamed-or-synonymed?rq=1)?

Comment: @Geobits Ah yes. Exactly that. I searched meta for it before posting, but it didn't show then :/