# Re-tag questions with [market] to [google-play],

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

All the questions tagged with [market](/questions/tagged/market) are also tagged with [android](/questions/tagged/android). This suggests that they are all refering to the [android-market](/questions/tagged/android-market).

Since the [android-market](/questions/tagged/android-market) tag [is a synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125140/android-market-tag-should-be-renamed-or-synonymed) of the [google-play](/questions/tagged/google-play) tag I suggest that all of the questions tagged [market](/questions/tagged/market) be re-tagged to [google-play](/questions/tagged/google-play).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you

Comment: You got my vote Sir! That's a new task for the Developer team now. It should be done if the Market of Apps is for Android!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there was 100% overlap, and the old [market](/questions/tagged/market) tag wiki suggested using the more specific [android-market](/questions/tagged/android-market) tag anyway, I went ahead and created a tag synonym and merged [market](/questions/tagged/market) into [google-play](/questions/tagged/google-play).